# ngx modal work with data

Tags: angular, typescript, ngx-bootstrap

I'm new in angular 5(and angular at all), so I have a few problems.
I wanna work with my data(books) in table, and when user press edit button,send the data from selected row to the edit modal window and open it. After editing close modal window and send updated data back to the table.

**Questions:**

1. How can I send the data from the row to the modal window?(each row has his own edit button).
2. How can I send updated data back to the table?

**Code:**

**fetch-data.component.ts**

```
import { Component, Inject, TemplateRef } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BsModalService } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';
import { BsModalRef } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal/bs-modal-ref.service';
import { ReactiveFormsModule, FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { Http, Headers, Response, RequestOptions, RequestMethod } from '@angular/http';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-fetch-data',
  templateUrl: './fetch-data.component.html'
})
export class FetchDataComponent {
  http: any;
  public books: Book[];
  public genres: Genre[];
  modalRef: BsModalRef;
  bookForm: FormGroup;
  public submitted: boolean;
  constructor(http: HttpClient, @Inject('BASE_URL') baseUrl: string, private modalService: BsModalService, private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.http = http;//test
    http.get<Book[]>(baseUrl + 'api/Book/GetAllBooks').subscribe(result => {
      this.books = result;
    }, error => console.error(error));
    http.get<Genre[]>(baseUrl + 'api/Book/GetAllGenres').subscribe(result => {
      this.genres = result;
    }, error => console.error(error));
  }
  public openModal(template: TemplateRef<any>) {
    this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(template);
  }
  public createForm() {
    this.bookForm = this.fb.group({
      name: ['', Validators.required],
      publisher: '',
      pages: '',
      genre: ''
    });
  }
  onSubmit({ value, valid }: { value: Book, valid: boolean }) {
    this.submitted = true;
    console.log(value);

    let body = JSON.stringify(value);

    console.log(body);

    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    return this.http.post('/api/referer/insert', body, options).subscribe();
  }
}

interface Book {
  bookName: string;
  publisher: number;
  pages: number;
  genre: Genre;
}

interface Genre {
  genreId: number;
  genreName: string;
}
```

**fetch-data.component.html**

```
<h1>Books</h1>
<p>This component demonstrates books</p>

<p *ngIf="!books"><em>Loading...</em></p>

<table class='table' *ngIf="books">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Book Name</th>
      <th>Publisher</th>
      <th>Pages</th>
      <th>Genre</th>
      <th>Edit</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let book of books">
      <td>{{ book.bookName }}</td>
      <td>{{ book.publisher }}</td>
      <td>{{ book.pages }}</td>
      <td>{{ book.genre.genreName }}</td>
      <td><button class="btn btn-warning" (click)="openModal(template)">Edit</button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<ng-template #template>
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title pull-left">Edit Window</h4>
    <button type="button" class="close pull-right" aria-label="Close" (click)="modalRef.hide()">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <h2>Book Editor</h2>
    <form  [formGroup]="bookForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(bookForm, bookForm.isValid)" >
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="center-block">
          Name:
          <input class="form-control" formControlName="name" placeholder="Name">
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="center-block">
          Publisher:
          <input class="form-control" formControlName="publisher" placeholder="Publisher">
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="center-block">
          Pages:
          <input class="form-control" formControlName="pages" placeholder="Pages">
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="center-block">
          Genre:
          <select class="form-control" formControlName="genre">
            <option *ngFor="let genre of genres" [value]="genre">{{genre}}</option><!--mb value i should change-->
          </select>
        </label>
      </div>
    </form>

    <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Edit</button>
    <button class="btn btn-danger" (click)="modalRef.hide()">Back to List</button>

    {{bookForm.value | json }}
  </div>

</ng-template>
```

Comment: you may pay attention to this library : https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview, here part who illustrate what you need. https://stackblitz.com/angular/gjjmqjveblek?file=app%2Fdialog-overview-example.ts

Comment: if you still want to use ngx-bootstrap. I prupose you this sample : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jjn5fx?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will try it today.